# Extract strings from given string in java

Tags: java, string

Consider following example,

```
String str = "Record of student " + 
              "Name: Aasim ; Surname: Khan; Age: 15 ; Weight: 60; " + 
              "School : Abcd High School This is record of Student";
```

I want in extract array of string which contains **Aasim, Khan, 60, Abcd High School**

Comment: Then write some Java to extract it. When you have a specific issue, then you should ask questions, of course, after you [do your research](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this :

```
   for (String retval: str.split(";")){
           String[] parts = retval.split(":");
           String neededPart = parts[1];
           // do your stuff with your neededPart
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, split your string by semicolon to get each key-value pair. Then split each part by colon.

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the data between Colan(:) and the semicolan(;).Add the retrived data to the string array. try to print it.Use the StringTokenizer class for getting the data between colan and semicolan.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to do it using regular expression:

For simplicity consider : `String str = "Record of student " + 
              "Name: Aasim ; Surname: Khan;`

```
import java.util.Pattern.*;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Record of student Name:(.*) ; Surname:(.*).*")
Matcher m = p.matcher(str)
if(m.matches()){
   String name = m.group(1);
   //so on
}
```

Comment: True :). But to start off with it might help to know which group is associated with which string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. The idea is to match the chains of characters (`\w` is an alphanumeric character in regexp) between `:` and `;`, as in the following sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".* : (\\w+) ; .*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("The first substring is: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Then all of the substrings will be in `m`, as you see in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer as the exemple below:

```
String str = "Record of student Name: Aasim ; Surname: Khan; Age: 15 ; Weight: 60; School : Abcd High School This is record of Student";

    ArrayList<String> tokens1=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tokens2=new ArrayList<>();


    StringTokenizer s1=new StringTokenizer(str, ";");
    while (s1.hasMoreElements()) {
        tokens1.add((String) s1.nextElement());
    }

    for (String string : tokens1) {
        System.out.println(string);
        StringTokenizer s2=new StringTokenizer(string, ":");

        int i=0;
        while (s2.hasMoreElements()) {
            s2.nextElement();
            tokens2.add((String) s2.nextElement());
        }
    }
    for (String string : tokens2) {

        System.out.println(string);
    }
```